# Start thread on main thread posted from main thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(MainActivity.context.getMainLooper());
mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        // .. some code                
    }
});
```

Normally I start `Runnable` from worker thread, but it can happen, that it is called from main thread. Do you think it has any negative side effect?

Answer (score 4):

You're not starting a thread, you're attaching a Handler to the main Looper and sending it a command to run. It will have the exact same effect as when it would be called from another thread.

Comment: Is it any 'delay' posting `Runnable` like this from main to main compare when a normal 'method call' is performed?!

Comment: @János Yes, those runnables get added to a queue which is executed after any previous things it had to do

Answer (score 0):

1. Handler will post the runnable to the looper it attached to. Runnable is just a code segment, it will be called on the thread that the looper running on. At this situation, the looper here is the MainLooper and the runnable will be called on the MainThread.

Whenever you want to update your UI component, you should post your runnable to the main thread.

2. I don't think it is good enough to declare a static field in MainActivity like this "MainActivity.context".

Comment: What is the problem with `"MainActivity.context".`? I am always in doubt why context always need when calling different methods. In iOS does not exist similar animal. So I just use anywhere context needs the `"MainActivity.context"`.

Comment: What does MainActivity.context reference to? Your Application or MainActivity?

Comment: `context = getApplicationContext();`

Comment: That's good, so why won't you use 'YourApplication.getContext()'?

Comment: If for some reason, codes turn out to be like this 'context = this' , memory leak may occur.

Answer (score -1):

Handler use when it is necessary to send a message to another thread.
If you create a Handler in main thread, then you can sent message from background thread to the main thread.
Better make new inner static class extends Hadnler, declare WeakReference var to Activity.